# Why does the comparison with integer works for nullptr?

Tags: c++11, nullptr

The following works for g++

```
assert(nullptr == 0);
```

I need to know if there is any implicit type conversion that is happening.
From what I know, `nullptr` can be compared with pointers only and not with integers, and also that it is more type-safe. Then why the comparison with integer works?

Answer (score 2):

> Then why the comparison with integer works?

Because, in most implementations, the `nullptr` is a 0 machine address. In other words `(intptr_t)nullptr` is 0. This is the case on Linux/x86-64 for example. Check by inspecting the generated assembler code obtained with `g++ -S -O2 -fverbose-asm`

I even believe that this is guaranteed by the C++ standard (read e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))

However, if you compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `gcc -Wall -Wextra` you could get a warning.

Read also [assert(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html). In some cases  (with `NDEBUG`) it is expanded to a no-op at compilation time.